# Метод strpos($txt," ");

Tags: php

Столкнулся с проблемой, когда строка на русском,
 метод `strpos($txt," ");`
 возвращает не правильную позицию символа

например $txt = "MySQL Cluster Supports"

echo $start = strpos($txt," ");

вернёт 5 а если переменной $txt = "Присвоить русские символы " то возвращает совсем не то!

в чём проблема?

Comment: что написал сам-то понял?

Comment: а что именно не понятно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

кодировка utf-8, все дело в ней. для правильного перебора mb_strpos, а если столкнетесь с тем чтобы узнать длину строки на русском языке, то используйте mb_strlen()

Answer (score 3):

[mb_strpos](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-strpos.php)